# Eyes of the Gods

Tags: idols, narasimha, art

I saw this image of Sri Narasimha statue :

[image]

Why His eyes are depicted in that way?

Comment: You mean why the eye balls bulging out? May be due to fury and anger?

Comment: I don't think so. It's something related to the puya itself.

Comment: I was searching any reference connected to the eyes during worship .